# If you alone discover that all forms of full anesthetic are ineffective, should you keep it a secret?

Tags: ethics

Suppose that you alone discover that full anesthetic only makes the user look unconscious and not form memories, but does not prevent him from feeling pain; if someone needs to undergo surgery, there is no way around that pain and suffering.

Should you keep this finding a secret?

Comment: I voted to close the question as it is very subjective.

Comment: Don't have an answer for you, just more questions:https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/55004/33787 and https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/55047/33787

Comment: Just one subjective opinion: in Robert Heinlein's books, he invented the "Lethe Field" which prevented you from forming memories of the surgery.  It was considered to be the ultimate boon to medical science, because a doctor could interact with a conscious patient, but they never had enough memory to realize they were in pain.  So that it at least one individual's opinion on the matter.

Comment: Related:  Some years ago, scientists published that they'd succeeded in curing alcoholics so that they could drink in moderation.  This was blasted by Alcoholics Anonymous as encouraging their members to drink again, in contrast to their policy of complete abstinence.

Comment: I think this question would be a fine time to analyze the various ethical concepts of pain, harm, help, healing, consent, etc.  Vote to reopen.

Comment: This is an ethics question.  There is a specific question about a well-described situation.  It's no more subjective than lots of questions here.  I'm not seeing why it should be closed or put on hold.  Voting to reopen.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The belief in painkillers aids the patients recovery. Placebo effect would encourage people to seek help, when neccessary.

Comment: To whoever downvoted this:  please leave a comment when downvoting a new contributor.  We don't want to discourage them.